# Several div are shifted away when array is reversed thus breaking the layout

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twig

So I use this PHP array to store information I need to build a simple HTML structure that looks like so:

```
{% for key, realisation in realisations %}
    <div class="{{ realisation.thumbnail.category }} col-md-4 item">
        <div class="grid">
            <figure class="effect-oscar">
                <img src="images/realisations/{{ realisation.thumbnail.image }}" alt="" />
                <figcaption>
                    <p>
                      <span>
                        {{ realisation.thumbnail.name }} &bull; {{ realisation.thumbnail.type }}
                      </span>
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="smooth-redirect" data-rea="{{ key }}"></a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

`{{ realisations }}` is a variable I pass to the Twig view:

```
return $this->render('views/partials/realisations.html.twig', [
    'realisations' => $realisations,
]);
```

Everything is going well and the `div` get into position nicely as per the screenshot:

[image]

However, I want to invert the position of the `div` so I get the one in the last position into the first position (`STEVE DAVID • SITE` would be first and `ZELDA-BOSS • SITE` would be last).

So I naturally go by:

```
return $this->render('views/partials/realisations.html.twig', [
    'realisations' => array_reverse($realisations), // use array_reverse()
]);
```

But once done, the layout is broken by one `div` that is shifted of one block and make the others one shifted as well, then leaving a blank space in the middle of the layout:

[image]

Does one would have even the slightest idea of what is going on and would be willing to help me?

Comment: Can you check how many elements you have in your *$realisations* array, with `count($realisations)`? There could be 10, and one with a non-existing image. You should put some text in the image's `alt` attributes.

Comment: @trincot: `{{ dump(realisations|length) }}` reports as `8` elements (same with `count($realisations)`). You're right about the `alt` attribute, just did :)

Comment: `{{ realisation.thumbnail.category }}` is a dynamically set CSS class that depends on whichever `realisation` is being rendered.  Is the value for this the same for all realisations?  Would you mind posting the "generated source" when the template is rendered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look a little closer, you will notice that `STEVE DAVID`'s box is `1px` taller than the other boxes. This `1px` is breaking your float grid. Try clearing the float on every `4th` element with CSS.

It would be something like:

```
.item:nth-child(4n+4) {}
```

Comment: You were right about the height of this specific box. Setting the same height in CSS did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: That was a nice catch!

Comment: I'm barely holding my eyes open. Don't ask me how i saw this! Glad i helped :)